# How do you find the closest square number to another number without using a calculator

Tags: square-numbers

Say we try to find the closest square number to 26. we already know the closest square number is $25$.
However, how do I calculate out 25?

> Because, if I try to prime factorize it like so: 
>   $\sqrt{26}$ = $\sqrt{2*13}$
>
> And I try to round 13 to the closest even number, I would get this equation here from prime factorization: 
>   $\sqrt{26}$ = $\sqrt{2*13}$ 
>   -> $\sqrt{2*2*2*3}$

Then, if I write out the equation, it wouls turn up as: 
$\sqrt{24}$ , 
Which is not 25.

I there a way to find out the closest square number to a certain number **without using a calculator**?

Comment: This is the same as asking [how to manually compute roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376365/how-to-manually-calculate-roots)

Comment: @lulu Not exactly because in that case, you are trying to compute roots but in my case, I don't know that case exactly what square number I'm computing

Comment: @UnidentifiedX You are wrong: if you have some number and compute the square root manually, just drop the fractional part from the result, square it and you will get the nearest perfect square smaller than the given number.

Comment: It is the same problem.  Coincidentally, the link I gave you specifically addresses $\sqrt {26}$.  They get approximately $5.1$.  It follows that the nearest square is either $5^2$ or $6^2$ and a simple calculation settles the point.

Answer (score -1):

You have to subtract all the digits but the first one from the number then add this to the original number. e.g  with 745, we would subtract the 45 as those are the digits after the first one. We are left with 700, we add 700 to 745 therefore are answer will be 1445. Weeeee did it!!